# ConnectTimeoutError while running 'pip install' via docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I'm new to docker and currently trying to build an image for my Django project. Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine
WORKDIR /my_project

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, execution breaks at the second pip command with the following error;

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f2b21bd1610>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect
> timeout=15)')': /simple/asgiref/

Some Context:

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS **Kernel**: Linux 5.8.0-34-generic

`docker --version` Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

`docker-compose --version` docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

I have gone through a lot of similar questions online but none of their corresponding solutions  work for me. I'll be more than glad to share any other info needed to assist in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sound there is some issue with the network connectivity while build the docker container.
Use `Host` as an network inside compose file to resolve the issue.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  django_image:
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
```

---

Give it a try and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me on Ubuntu:

Update the Docker daemon

Create this file with the following: Your network’s DNS server, and for backup the Google DNS server.

/etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Then restart the docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: THANK YOU... I've been trying for like 3 hours to get this resolved. My pip installs used to run on Docker, but for some reason stopped, and returned this error!
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at xxxx>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /my-python-library/

went to C:\Users\myuser\.docker\deamon.json and added that key:value pair, restarted and voila.. worked like a charm