# ConnectTimeoutError for 'pip install' on Windows-based docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I'm in the process of learning Docker, and I've run into this timeout error while trying to follow along with a tutorial.

The Dockerfile:

```
###Base image:###

FROM python:alpine

###Add app code to /code inside container image:###

ADD . /code

###Set working directory for subsequent commands:###

WORKDIR /code

###Install dependencies:###

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

###Command to run when container starts:###

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

When I try to run the command 'docker-compose up -d' I get the following error message:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1dcd757290>,'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/flask/

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

docker --version: Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243

docker-compose --version: Docker Compose version v2.15.1

I've gone over numerous suggestions online, including the one presented in " [ConnectTimeoutError while running 'pip install' via docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642356/connecttimeouterror-while-running-pip-install-via-docker-compose) " and none that I've found have worked for my situation.